# How can I add app-wrappers endpoint to Restplus API documentation?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have a Flask REST API. I use [`healthcheck.EnvironmentDump`](https://pypi.org/project/py-healthcheck/) to make it easy to dump the environment where my service is running. Is it possible to add the endpoint to the Swagger documentation generated by Restplus?

### Example

requirements.txt

```
flask
flask-restplus
gitpython
healthcheck
```

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Simple Flask/Swagger/REST-API example."""

from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from healthcheck import EnvironmentDump

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, doc='/doc')

# wrap the flask app and give a environment url
# TODO: Add this to API
envdump = EnvironmentDump(app, "/environment")


@api.route('/version')
class VersionAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        import git
        repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
        sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
        return sha


@api.route('/health')
class HealthAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 2):

EnvironmentDump and HealthCheck will each install their own handlers for the endpoint, so your get() instances within your defined Resources will not be reached. That being said, providing a stubbed resource is sufficient for it to show up in the Swagger doc generated by Flask-RESTPlus:

```
health = HealthCheck(app, '/healthcheck')

@api.route('/healthcheck')
class HealthCheckResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
```